# javascript, keep getting undefined in loop

Tags: javascript

I have this code, but for some reason I keep getting colours.undefined

```
var varray = new Array("WH", "BL");
var fname = "colours",
    lname = "size_code_id";
var arr = new Array();
var mquery = {
    "$or": []
};
for (var i = 0; i < varray.length; i++); {
    var query = {
        "$and": []
    };
    var s1 = fname.concat(".").concat(varray[i]);
    var s2 = fname.concat(".").concat(varray[i]).concat(".").concat(lname);
    var sub1 = {}, sub2 = {};

    sub1[s1] = {
        $exists: 1
    };
    sub2[s2] = "S";

    query["$and"].push(sub1);
    query["$and"].push(sub2);

    arr.push(query);
};
```

I want to get `colours.WH.size_code_id` but keep getting `colours.undefined.size_code_id`

What am i missing, any advice much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `;` after

```
for (var i = 0; i < varray.length; i++) ; {
```

*Example*

```js
var varray = new Array("WH", "BL");

var fname = "colours",
    lname = "size_code_id";

var arr = new Array();

var mquery = {
    "$or": []
};

for (var i = 0; i < varray.length; i++) {
    var query = {
        "$and": []
    };
    var s1 = fname.concat(".").concat(varray[i]);
    var s2 = fname.concat(".").concat(varray[i]).concat(".").concat(lname);
    var sub1 = {}, sub2 = {};

    sub1[s1] = {
        $exists: 1
    };
    sub2[s2] = "S";

    query["$and"].push(sub1);
    query["$and"].push(sub2);

    arr.push(query);
};

console.log(arr)
```